# Why is my armature being mirrored this way?

Tags: armature

I'm trying to symmetrize this armature, but clearly it's not working properly and I don't know what the problem is. I thought maybe it was because some bones are missing the ".L" in their name, but I checked and none of them are missing the .L. I'm guessing it has something to do with the origin and its position, but I honestly don't know how that works or how to fix that. I tried rotating the armature on the z axis to see if it would be mirrored in the right way but it didn't work. I've never had this problem before and I've run out of ideas so any help would be appreciated.

Plus, I would like an explanation on how to set origins properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The *Symmetrize* operation happens on the X axis, your armature is currently aligned on Y, therefore you need to rotate your armature 90° on Z in *Edit* mode and try again.

Comment: It's still not working even after trying that

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/